# Finding element beneath on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to determine which element is beneath a given element on a page?  I have a tool that I would like to use over several elements which are visible only one at a time.  I'd like to be able to determine which element is visible under that given element.  Can this be done?

Comment: immediate benieath ?????? siblings or descendents ?

Comment: I think he means visually, on the screen, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was about finding the element closet to a point or an element.  This plug-in does this:
[jquery nearest](http://gilmoreorless.github.com/jquery-nearest/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reliably do this natively in JavaScript. CSS can effect the layout in ways that you can not predict.

I can think of one solution where you find *all* the elements on the page and their offsets and then try to work back from that, but that wont perform very well I suspect.

Comment: I don't understand why you posted that .. functions like `.next` return the element after it based on where it occurs in the DOM tree, not where it appears on the screen, which I think what OP is after.

Comment: Your comment is based on a different interpretation of the OPs question (if that's what you mean by skinning cats). Just make your own answer?

Comment: I think it would be more clear if you posted your own answer, then you're free to remove your comment here at your own volition.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the immediately following sibling (in a set of matched elements) with the jQuery `.next()` function:

http://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case I can think of several options.

One option would be triggering a click event onto the container and then selecting the event.target in the event handler. It should be the element on top.

like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/sm7gH/